# Currently working through ODE exercise book and troubling question has appeared and i cant find any useful info to help with the it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm currently completing a exercise sheet on ODEs and I'm having trouble arriving at the answer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Given the following differential equations:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
dx/dt = -x + y -1\\\\
dy/dt = -x - y + 3
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

When $t = 0$, $x = 0$ and $y = 3$.

a) Find the general solution for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you solved similar problems by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the response Paul. I haven't tried anything I'm just at a loss to be honest

Comment: I have now tried integrating the sides with respect to t but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate both sides of the first equation:

$x'' = -x' + y'$ (3)

Sub (2) into (3):

$x'' = -x' + (-x - y + 3)$

$x'' = -x' - x - y + 3$ (4)

Rearrange (1) and sub into (4):

$x'' = -x' - x - (x' + x + 1) + 3$

$x'' = -x' - x - x' - x + 2$

$x'' + 2x' + 2x - 2 = 0$

Solve for $x(t)$ then sub into (1) to solve for $y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I believe you missed the '+3' on the 4th line but considering that I ended up with: x(t) = e^-t(Acost+Bsint)+1 and y(t)=Acos(sqrt2.t)+Bsin(sqrt2.t)+2